# Oracle script client that exports query result as UPDATE statement

Tags: oracle, toad, sql-navigator

I use Quest TOAD for Oracle and Quest SQL Navigator for Oracle as my database 
query tools of choice.

These tools allow me to export the query results grid as INSERT statements.

For example

```
SELECT dummy  
FROM dual;
```

exports to

```
INSERT INTO dual
(DUMMY)
VALUES
('X')
/
```

Is there an Oracle database query tool that exports query results as UPDATE statements?

For example

```
SELECT dummy  
FROM dual;
```

would export to

```
UPDATE dual
SET dummy = 'X'
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one: http://www.sql-workbench.net

Comment: This does what I'm looking for. It makes scripting inserts, updates and deletes super easy!

Comment: Just used this tool to do this. It's very nice!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are other tools (wasn't able to find one, to be precise).

What I used to do for this to export the data as `CSV`, then hack a quick `awk` script to generate the desired `UPDATE`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the Insert query first, insert into a backup table. Then update the target table with the backup table with PK.

```
UPDATE (SELECT tr.id, 
               tr.name a,
               tr.desc b,
               bk.name A,
               bk.desc B
          FROM target tr,
               backup bk
         WHERE tr.id = bk.id)
   SET a = A,
       b = B
```